# Use field calculator to return the word after "unit"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.5, address-parsing

Working on ArcMap Desktop 10.5; the file in question lives in a file gdb. I have a polygon layer with a field of full property addresses (string) from which I need to extract ONLY the unit number, to be populated in a new blank field STUNIT (string). The addresses are all different lengths depending on presence of street direction, etc. so my addresses, for example, could look something like this:

1 BOXER ST UNIT 7A FARMINGTON

945 WILD TURKEY XING UNIT 116 TURTLE ISLAND

52 W CLAIRMONT DR UNIT J17 EASTHAVEN

I have already performed a selection to return only records which contain the word "UNIT", about 4000 records. My goal is to populate my STUNIT field using the python parser in field calculator, with ONLY the "word" directly following UNIT. I have tried variations of the split function which looks something like this

```
!AddressField!.split("UNIT")[0]
```

but, without fail, get the  following error messages:

- Whitespace is not allowed at this location
- This row contains a bad value (for both the shapefile itself and the field I tried to populate)

I have checked for spaces within/outside of the function but none exist. I have also tried a variant where I use find and replace to add a * to the end of the word "UNIT" and use the * as the delimiter in the function, but get identical results. Can a word in a string field be used as a delimiter for the split function in Arcpy? If so, what am I doing wrong/if not, is there another workaround that does not require a return on the *n*th object?

I have several years experience with ArcGIS but relatively new to python.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in the field calculator using regex.  Finds the word `UNIT` and returns the next word.  If it doesn't find `UNIT` then it won't return anything.

In the Field Calculator check Python parser, and Show Codeblock.  In the Pre-logic script code enter:

```
import re
def nextword(s):
    m = re.search('\\UNIT (\w+)', s)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
```

And in the expression:

```
nextword(!AddressField!)
```

[image]

Comment: After hours of research, this method worked beautifully. Thank you so much! I'm surprised that this is not a more commonly discussed problem in GIS addressing.

Comment: @amarshall Addresses are discussed fairly regularly both here and on [so].  Everyone stores and deals with addresses differently, and often people run into problems like yours when processes need to change and addresses have to be repackaged in a different way to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to define a function for this because it will go beyond basic manipulation of the field value.

enable the show codeblock button in field caluclator and in the the pre-logic script code area try this:

```
def split(AddrField):
    target = ((AddrField.split("UNIT")[1]).split(" "))[1]
    return target
```

then in field cal area below pass the field as the function's parameter:

```
split(!AddressField!)
```

Comment: What if there isn't a `UNIT` in the value?  Might need to check for the value first

Comment: OP: "I have already performed a selection to return only records which contain the word "UNIT", about 4000 records"

Comment: That may be the case now, but for future users it would eliminate the need to pre-select anything.  +1 anyway, tidier than mine and doesn't require `re` (I'm not a fan of regex)

Comment: Thank you, atxgis. I ended up using the solution presented by Midavalo, but just for training sake, can you help me understand why your solution didn't work with my data? I pasted your code in exactly as written, but changed instances of "AddressField" to the name of my actual address field. I got the following errors:
-Error running expression: split (-->for one specific address)
-Traceback (most recent call last):
-File "<expression>, line 1, in <module>
-File "<string>", line 2, in split
-Index Error: list index out of range

Comment: @amarshall I *think* that will happen if you try to process on a value that does not have the word `UNIT` in it.  I also get `list index out of range` when I try it on a value without `UNIT` but it works perfectly on values that do contain `UNIT`

Comment: Interesting. Sure, from your error it looks like after splitting the string the list index [1] did not exist in some of the field values. Maybe there are some values that do not have anything before or after the word UNIT?

Comment: @amarshall Also note that python is case picky - `UNIT` is different from `unit` and `Unit`

Comment: Those were my instincts too, but after looking back through my data, every instance of UNIT is in caps and has something before and after it. And my selection only contains values with the word "UNIT" - otherwise this would be a much, much larger dataset. Tried again with atxgis code - still to no avail.

Comment: well, its hard to say without looking at the data, but a "list index out of range" error means that there was not a result from the split.

Comment: @amarshall If you select just one or two records does it work?

Comment: @Midavalo I am beginning to think that there is some funky issue with my original data. When I got your code to work, I used a very small subset of records and copied the address field into a completely new field, but handwrote them instead of using field calc. When I tried again, with the original field and larger dataset, I got error messages. In a similar concern, I tried to run a find and replace to exchange spaces for dashes (-) in the original field and F&R did not recognize any space beyond the first one in each record. If F&R doesn't recognize a space, why would field calc?

Comment: Will try some data repair strategies back in the office on Monday. The data in its original source comes from our board of assessors (read: not necessarily created for GIS) and so I would not be surprised to find that it contains a funky error of sorts that's throwing this whole deal off.

Comment: For closure and for future readers, I discovered two issues that were giving me error messages:
1. My unit field had a cap of 4 characters, and there were two addresses in which the unit was 5 characters long. This kicked the switch for the entire process.
2. You were right @atxgis, a handful of address values did NOT have any word after "UNIT," also because of a character cap in the field. It seems the absence of the word "UNIT" in an address provides no setbacks and simply returns null, but if it DOES contain "UNIT" it must have a word after it for this to work.